# Getting id or xpath of parts of a website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to use selenium to login in the website https://www.winamax.es/account/login.php?redir=/apuestas-deportivas. The case is that I don't find the xpath/id/text to get te next code running successfully:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.winamax.es/account/login.php?redir=/apuestas-deportivas")
WebDriverWait(driver=driver, timeout=15).until(
    lambda x: x.execute_script("return document.readyState === 'complete'")
)
upload_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']")
```

I don't only want the specific xpath for this example, but I prefer a method to obtain the xpath or something similar to get the code working for other parts of the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *email* element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.winamax.es/account/login.php?redir=/apuestas-deportivas")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#iframe-login")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='email']"))).send_keys("scraper@stackoverflow.com")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.winamax.es/account/login.php?redir=/apuestas-deportivas")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='iframe-login']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='email']"))).send_keys("scraper@stackoverflow.com")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: winamax]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked for me. But in order to completely understand your solution could you tell me why you use the line `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='iframe-login']"))) `? I don't understand what it does, cause I cannot see any iframe block in the html neither the id 'iframe-login'.

Comment: @scraper You can properly switch within an `<iframe>` only when the iframe is properly loaded i.e. the iframe is available to switch selenium's focus in it. Hence the usage of the expected_conditions `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`

Comment: I got you, but I would like to know where did you find the <iframe> or id="iframe-login". Cause in the html I cannot find it.

Comment: @scraper Open the developer console, inspect the **email** element and then traverse upwards, you can find the `<iframe>` tag within which the desired element resides.

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe id="iframe-login" data-node="iframe" name="login" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1" style="min-height: 280px; width: 100%;"></iframe>
```

Your element is in an iframe. Switch to it.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "iframe-login")))
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Full working code.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.winamax.es/account/login.php?redir=/apuestas-deportivas")
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "iframe-login")))
upload_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='email']")))
upload_field.send_keys("stuff")
```